# How to update existing array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have function update tag, user can remove or add new tag.
[image]

this is the output of the temp

```
tag_temp = [{
    db_id: 5,
    id: 1,
    name: 'Add Product'
  },
  {
    db_id: 6,
    id: 2,
    name: 'New'
  }, {
    db_id: 7,
    id: 3,
    name: 'Test'
  }
];
```

this is how I do it to achieve the above output.

```
  if(e.tag.length > 0){
     e.tag.map((e) => {
       tag_temp.push({
         "db_id" : e.db_id,
          'id'   : e.tag_id ,
          'name' : e.tag_name,
      });
   });
  console.log(tag_temp);
}
```

And now I want to perform update function, I have to compare the existing tag and push it into the finalized temp to fulfill my API Request.

I have this in my Postman API Request

```
"assign_tag":[
    {
        "db_id": 1,
        "tag_id": 3,
        "status": false
    },
    {
        "db_id": null,
        "tag_id": 3,
        "status": true
    }],
```

this is what I have tried on the update button

But I got error with

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined at the line `=== e.db_id)[0].db_id;`

```
finalized_temp = [];
        tag_temp = tag_temp.filter(function (el){
            if (el != null){

                let db_id = tag_temp.filter((el) => el.id  === e.db_id)[0].db_id;
                let tag_id = tag_temp.filter((el) => el.id === e.tag_id)[0].tag_id;
                let status = true;

                finalized_temp.push({
                    "db_id" : db_id,
                    "tag_id" : tag_id,
                    "status" : status

                })
            }

        });
```

I have to send data like this if I want to perform the update function how do I fix this problem ?

Example on how the concept is.

```js
//tag_temp is current fetching of select option before updating into the new final_temp.
let tag_temp = [{
    db_id: 5,
    id: 1,
    name: 'Add Product'
  },
  {
    db_id: 6,
    id: 2,
    name: 'New'
  }, {
    db_id: 7,
    id: 3,
    name: 'Test'
  }
];




$(document).ready(function() {
  updateTag();
});

const updateTag = () => {
let finalized_temp =[]
  let status = false;

  //if db_id is null meaning status is set to true.

    
  finalized_temp = [{
      db_id: 5,
      tag_id: 1,
      status: 'false',
    },
    {
      db_id: null,
      tag_id: 4,
      status: 'true',
    }
  ];


  console.log(finalized_temp);

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<label>Previous selected Tag :</label>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="mytitle">
  <option value="1" selected>Add Product</option>
  <option value="2" selected>New</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Test </option>
  <option value="4">Others</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
<label>New Selected Tag :</label>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="mytitle">
  <option value="1" selected>Add Product</option>
  <option value="2">New</option>
  <option value="3">Test</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Others</option>
</select>
```

the logic for this is

```
// db_id null is because new data is inserted to the array so the status need to be changed into 'true' otherwise it will be set to 'false'
if(db_id == '' || db_id == null)
 status = true
```

my expected output data will be like this

```
finalized_temp = [{
          db_id: 5,
          tag_id: 1,
          status: 'false',
        },
        {
          db_id: null,
          tag_id: 3,
          status: 'true',
        }
      ];
```

Comment: Do you just want to have an array with keys `db_id` and `tag_id` from `tag_temp` array and `status` as true always?

Comment: @Nitheesh  Yes I want to have array with `db_id` and `tag_id` from `tag_temp` . Status will be change to `true` if db_id is null. Meaning that if the array value is not existed in the array status will be true, if its already existed it the status will be `false` . Is that possible to do so ?

Comment: Please post the sample values for `tag_temp` and expected value for `db_id` and `tag_id`

Comment: @Nitheesh I already include the example output for the temp.

Comment: The question is basically convertion of one structured array into another. So it will be really helpful and redable if you could add the input data, expected output data, and logic for converting this input to output. The question is a little unclear. Reading the same, cannot get details for the same I asked.

Comment: What is the required output for this input?

Comment: @Nitheesh I'm sorry for the misunderstanding your question, and I have update the question and providing all the information that u asked.

Comment: So you are generating `finalized_temp` from `tag_temp` with the condition as  `db_id` is mapped as `db_id` and  `id` tagged as `tag_id`  and `status` will be true if `db_id` is null. In your question, none of the db_id is null. So is the input and output comination are correct?

Comment: yes i'm generating `finalized_temp` from the `tag_temp`. none of the `db_id` is null because the value already inserted in the Database.  `tag_temp` and `finalized temp` are from different function. ` db_id` is null because new item is inserted into the `finalized_temp`. yes input and output are correct.

Comment: in `tag_temp` none of the `db_id` are null, then how the status in `finalized_temp` is `true` in your output? for the input `const tag_temp = [{
  db_id: 5,
  id: 1,
  name: 'Add Product'
},
{
  db_id: 6,
  id: 2,
  name: 'New'
}, {
  db_id: 7,
  id: 3,
  name: 'Test'
}]`
Output should be
`const finalized_temp = [{
  db_id: 5,
  tag_id: 1,
  status: 'false',
},
{
  db_id: 6,
  tag_id: 2,
  status: 'false',
},
{
  db_id: 7,
  tag_id: 3,
  status: 'false',
}
]`

Comment: yes because I retrieve data from database and put it inside the `tag_temp`  that is why none of it is null. Now I want to perform update function using the `finalized_temp` . So if user unselected the option it will be remove , new item will be added and unchanged item will stay in `finalized_temp` . This `finalized_temp` value will be store into database.

Comment: as for the status, I have to perform if else condition. if  `db_id`  is null it will set into `true` which is I'm currently stuck on how to perform this current operation